# Phonegap canvas low refresh rate

Tags: javascript, android, performance, canvas, cordova

I am building a canvas based web game that runs at 60fps in chrome on the desktop. It also runs at 60fps in chrome on android. I loaded it into a phonegap application and the fps meter still reads 60fps, but the screen is only getting drawn every few ticks. Is there a refresh rate limiter that is forcing the webview to only draw every once a second or so? What other things could be limiting my drawing, even when the website says its redrawing at 60fps?

Comment: Maybe would you have better performance with the following plugin (needs full screen canvas and does not implement all canvas functions) https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas

Comment: Are you controlling the redraws with `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: I will look into fastcanvas, but I was hoping I would not have to. Yes I am using requestanimationframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PhoneGap by default will use the built in default browser, which is not chrome, unless you are working with KitKat, but that is a different story.

Now I had problems myself with the default browser even on small canvas project like getting a user signature, but that was due to low rate of touchevent fires...

Anyway the possible solution will be to force phonegap to use WebChromeClient instead of the default one, you can do that by adding following line before the `super.loadUrl` call:

```
appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

If you do force to use WebChromeClient make sure you do enable javascript, local storage if you need it and so on. Also it's possible that some PhoneGap plugins will break. If you game is pure HTML5 than I suggest considering not using phonegap for your android version, building a simple WebView app it is quite easy in Android.

Also if your game intend to use acceleration sensor, have a look at what is the native support for browsers: [Can I Use resources](http://caniuse.com/#feat=deviceorientation)

Also I will definitely read [THIS](http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools) and [THIS](http://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/jsAPI/canvas/index.html)

Hope it helped.
Emil

Comment: This is a very interesting reply. For the record, I am using kitkat. It is running chrome in the webview. The odd part is that it runs at 60fps outside of phonegap, and 60fps inside of phone gap (as outputted via xStats), the only difference being that it is only PHYSICALLY redrawing for me at about 2fps. Is there some other abstraction layer above phonegap that im not seeing? Is this a common behavior for canvas lacking certain abilities in phonegap?

Comment: Yes I'm afraid so, I did further reading and it seem to be a problem with PhoneGap, wasn't able to fund the exact WHY. It looks like that not even Andorid 4.4 default browser supports WebGl, while Chrome does (open Chrome on your browser and type: about://gpu). You can try to force the GPU, with tricks revealed here: http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d. To be able to give you more precise documentation I did even further digging and I can confirm that not even KitKat Chromium powered webview has support for WebGL (see: http://buff.ly/JjQSm8 )

Comment: Whit all this said and put together I think you should try to look for alternate solutions. Either FastCavans suggested by QuickFix or Intel XDK suggested by myself (which I'm downloading now to have a play around). Also I forgot to mention, it looks 100% STUPID, but make sure you have Hardware acceleration enabled in your Manifest <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your efforts Emil. Enjoy the bounty :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the new Webview does not have all the same features as Chrome. One of these differences is the WebGL 3D canvas that Chrome uses. See [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android) for a list of feature differences between the new Webview and Chrome.